# How to profile CSS selectors?

Tags: css, performance

1) Google removed the CSS Profiler from Blink (Issue #265486)

2) Firefox doesn't have one (Issue #713031) (The fun fact is that someone a couple of years ago asked a chrome-like profiler... and now they got it!)

3) Opera had dragonfly, but now Opera is Blink based... and dragonfly is gone.

4) The only profiler still around there, the one in Safari, doesn't work on my 6.0.5 / OSX 10.8.5. (it keeps recording css and I can't stop it)

Moreover, this should be browser dependent so testing only one browser is not the best choice.

I know about the tool "CSS-Stress-Testing-and-Performance-Profiling" but I didn't figure it out how to use that for my purposes.

I came across some benchmarks like: http://jsperf.com/css-selector-speed/15 and basing on that one I wrote stuff like this: https://gist.github.com/tagliala/7009411

The chromium guys say that "CSS selector matching is now reasonably fast for the absolute majority of common selectors that used to be slow at the time of the profiler implementation", well...

How can I check if it's worth it change syntax from ".icon-*" to ".font-icon.font-icon-*" to avoid universal rules like "[class*=icon-], [class*= icon-]" ? That is what Bootstrap 3.0 did for Glyphicons and FontAwesome is planning for 4.0

Thanks and sorry for my English!

Comment: I guess that you shouldn't really worry about this..

Comment: [class*=icon-] is not a universal selector it is an Attribute Selector that finds the sub-string whose value contains at least one occurrence of string .. the * by itself is considered the universal selector.. which is sometimes frowned upon because it is very slow

Comment: Based on the reasoning given I would simply assume that it's really not worth it.

Comment: @jonathan, `*` isn't frowned upon because it's slow, it's frowned upon because you're overwriting styles for *everything*, which is a terrible idea and makes maintenance a nightmare.

Comment: @zzzzBov i see your point.. but that is not the reason because you could use the universal selector as a reset before other styles, say for margins and paddings.. but is very slow and is considered the most EXPENSIVE css selector due to how slow it is and can slow loading of web pages.. see this test.. http://stevesouders.com/efws/css-selectors/universal.php - also checkout the note on this page for Mozilla .. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors .. also check out this: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/18/simplifying-css-selectors/

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS, [class^=icon-] is a universal rule. Since I mean rule, I edited the question. According to that "old" document,
"Guidelines for efficient CSS

Avoid universal rules

Make sure a rule doesn’t end up in the universal category!"

Comment: Any selector without a type selector uses an implied universal selector so... there's that.

Answer (score 0):

Modern web development is trending away from profiling CSS selectors simply because there's so little to be gained from it. It would take a lot of time and effort to make any noticeable change in performance, and would likely hamper the maintainability of the code.

Given the speed at which selectors are parsed, you'd be better off focusing on other aspects of the website which could use a performance gain.

Simply removing a single image from the page would likely improve your site's performance more than any amount of CSS refactoring could.

Comment: Thanks but there are no images in FontAwesome, I just need to profile CSS selectors in all major browsers.

Comment: This may be true in case of powerful desktop computers, but a lot of mobile devices (smartphones, tablets, etc.) are VERY slow. Abusing CSS may cause dramatic decrease in performance on them. Also some older browsers like IE8 are significantly slower in parsing CSS so it's always good to be able to determine which settings are optimal in terms of CSS parsing speed.

Answer (score 0):

Until any better solution is created you can continue to use Opera 12.x with Dragonfly which still does the job.

You can download older versions of Opera here: http://ftp.opera.com/pub/opera/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is that browsers css performance evolved and testing an obsolete version of Opera is not the same of testing modern versions of all browsers

Comment: @tagliala Opera 12.16 is less than one year old so it's not that old yet... A lot of other web browsers still used today are way older than that (such as the default browser included in older versions of Android). I think Opera 12.x with its profiler is still sufficient if you need to check whether there's any particular CSS rule that has noticeable impact on performance. From my observation, the browsers that struggle with CSS are usually the older ones (IE8, etc.) rather than the newest versions of Firefox or Chrome :)